# ValidationException When Running wsimport

Tags: validation, certificate, wsimport

I am trying to generate client code for a wsdl using the JAX-WS RI wsimport tool.  When I ran the it I get this error:

> [ERROR] sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I came across this blog which has a neat little program to install certificates:

http://blogs.oracle.com/andreas/entry/no_more_unable_to_find

After copying the generated "jssecacerts" file to my [JAVA_HOME]/jre/lib directory and also copying it in the same directed named "cacerts" (there wasn't one), I still get the same error when re-running the wsimport.

So, I copied the "cacerts" file to my [JAX-WS_HOME]\lib as well and still get the same error.

Does anyone know how I can get wsimport to work?

Comment: link down : http://blogs.oracle.com/andreas/entry/no_more_unable_to_find

Comment: someone made a copy :
http://nodsw.com/blog/leeland/2006/12/06-no-more-unable-find-valid-certification-path-requested-target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I needed to copy the file to [JAVA_HOME]/jre/lib/security (versus [JAVA_HOME]/jre/lib).

[sigh....]